ts(4023) when using project references
TypeScript Version: Version 5.4.5
Example
a simple example with three project are main,module and type. main project rederences module,and module project references type.
project type
type/a.ts
interface GetMedia {}
export const get: GetMedia = null as any;

type/index.ts
import { get } from "./a";
export type Get = typeof get;

project module
module/index.ts
import type { Get } from "../type";
const get: Get = null as any;
export const api = {
  get,
};

config files
tsconfig.json
{
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.module.json"
        }
    ]
}

tsconfig.type.json
{
    "include": [
        "type/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true
    }
}

tsconfig.type.json
{
    "include": [
        "type/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true
    }
}

What happen
Exported variable 'api' has or is using name 'GetMedia' from external module "f:/now now now/t/type/a" but cannot be named.ts(4023)\
I have read issues #5711 #9944 24666.It looks like a old problems .
Is this expected behavior or a bug?
